# How do i restore my usb's space back to 32 GB

Tags: usb

Recently i created a bootable windows installer using RUFUS. after doing it i saw that it is now 29.4 GB, how can i restore it back to 32 GB?

[image: The drive's space]

Answer (score 5):

You fell victim to the marketing slogans illustrated by this [WikiPedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

So, according to the definition in the above link, your drive probably has a capacity of

```
32GB (32*1000*1000*1000 bytes)
```

But because the free space is calculated in GiB, the *real* capacity is

```
32,000,000,000 / (1024*1024*1024) = 29.80 GiB (gibibyte)
```

The rest of the difference may be due to filesystem overhead and such.